# Efficient correlation calculation between large number of records

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, correlation

I am reading a book ([A Programmer's Guide to Data Mining](http://guidetodatamining.com/)) which has the following data attached to it [BX-Dump](http://guidetodatamining.com/guide/ch2/BX-Dump.zip), having 100k users' rating, each having some books rated. I'd like to move the whole dataset into pandas dataframe, which loads 10x faster than the author's implementation:

```
%time r.loadBookDB('/Users/danialt/Downloads/BX-Dump/')
1700018
CPU times: user 16.1 s, sys: 373 ms, total: 16.5 s
Wall time: 16.5 s
```

and mine:

```
# Mine
%time ratings = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
%time books = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Books.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
%time users = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Users.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")

#Output[5]
 CPU times: user 484 ms, sys: 73.3 ms, total: 557 ms
 Wall time: 567 ms
 CPU times: user 1.28 s, sys: 138 ms, total: 1.41 s
 Wall time: 1.45 s
 CPU times: user 148 ms, sys: 25.7 ms, total: 173 ms
 Wall time: 178 ms
#/Output
```

Now, to calculate the correlation `ratings.corr()` I need to put users on index, and books on columns, and the ratings as values:

```
ratings_piv = ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
```

But this is going to fail, since there would be a 100k x 400k matrix formed!

Is there a better/elegant way of calculating correlation this very sparse matrix without looping though each row?

A example code: (do not run the last line, it will kill your RAM)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import codecs 
from math import sqrt

users = {"Angelica": {"Blues Traveler": 3.5, "Broken Bells": 2.0,
                      "Norah Jones": 4.5, "Phoenix": 5.0,
                      "Slightly Stoopid": 1.5,
                      "The Strokes": 2.5, "Vampire Weekend": 2.0},

         "Bill":{"Blues Traveler": 2.0, "Broken Bells": 3.5,
                 "Deadmau5": 4.0, "Phoenix": 2.0,
                 "Slightly Stoopid": 3.5, "Vampire Weekend": 3.0},

         "Chan": {"Blues Traveler": 5.0, "Broken Bells": 1.0,
                  "Deadmau5": 1.0, "Norah Jones": 3.0, "Phoenix": 5,
                  "Slightly Stoopid": 1.0},

         "Dan": {"Blues Traveler": 3.0, "Broken Bells": 4.0,
                 "Deadmau5": 4.5, "Phoenix": 3.0,
                 "Slightly Stoopid": 4.5, "The Strokes": 4.0,
                 "Vampire Weekend": 2.0},

         "Hailey": {"Broken Bells": 4.0, "Deadmau5": 1.0,
                    "Norah Jones": 4.0, "The Strokes": 4.0,
                    "Vampire Weekend": 1.0},

         "Jordyn":  {"Broken Bells": 4.5, "Deadmau5": 4.0,
                     "Norah Jones": 5.0, "Phoenix": 5.0,
                     "Slightly Stoopid": 4.5, "The Strokes": 4.0,
                     "Vampire Weekend": 4.0},

         "Sam": {"Blues Traveler": 5.0, "Broken Bells": 2.0,
                 "Norah Jones": 3.0, "Phoenix": 5.0,
                 "Slightly Stoopid": 4.0, "The Strokes": 5.0},

         "Veronica": {"Blues Traveler": 3.0, "Norah Jones": 5.0,
                      "Phoenix": 4.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 2.5,
                      "The Strokes": 3.0}
        }

class recommender:

    def __init__(self, data, k=1, metric='pearson', n=5):
        """ initialize recommender
        currently, if data is dictionary the recommender is initialized
        to it.
        For all other data types of data, no initialization occurs
        k is the k value for k nearest neighbor
        metric is which distance formula to use
        n is the maximum number of recommendations to make"""
        self.k = k
        self.n = n
        self.username2id = {}
        self.userid2name = {}
        self.productid2name = {}
        # for some reason I want to save the name of the metric
        self.metric = metric
        if self.metric == 'pearson':
            self.fn = self.pearson
        #
        # if data is dictionary set recommender data to it
        #
        if type(data).__name__ == 'dict':
            self.data = data

    def convertProductID2name(self, id):
        """Given product id number return product name"""
        if id in self.productid2name:
            return self.productid2name[id]
        else:
            return id


    def userRatings(self, id, n):
        """Return n top ratings for user with id"""
        print ("Ratings for " + self.userid2name[id])
        ratings = self.data[id]
        print(len(ratings))
        ratings = list(ratings.items())
        ratings = [(self.convertProductID2name(k), v)
                   for (k, v) in ratings]
        # finally sort and return
        ratings.sort(key=lambda artistTuple: artistTuple[1],
                     reverse = True)
        ratings = ratings[:n]
        for rating in ratings:
            print("%s\t%i" % (rating[0], rating[1]))




    def loadBookDB(self, path=''):
        """loads the BX book dataset. Path is where the BX files are
        located"""
        self.data = {}
        i = 0
        #
        # First load book ratings into self.data
        #
        f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Book-Ratings.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            #separate line into fields
            fields = line.split(';')
            user = fields[0].strip('"')
            book = fields[1].strip('"')
            rating = int(fields[2].strip().strip('"'))
            if user in self.data:
                currentRatings = self.data[user]
            else:
                currentRatings = {}
            currentRatings[book] = rating
            self.data[user] = currentRatings
        f.close()
        #
        # Now load books into self.productid2name
        # Books contains isbn, title, and author among other fields
        #
        f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Books.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            #separate line into fields
            fields = line.split(';')
            isbn = fields[0].strip('"')
            title = fields[1].strip('"')
            author = fields[2].strip().strip('"')
            title = title + ' by ' + author
            self.productid2name[isbn] = title
        f.close()
        #
        #  Now load user info into both self.userid2name and
        #  self.username2id
        #
        f = codecs.open(path + "BX-Users.csv", 'r', 'utf8')
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            #print(line)
            #separate line into fields
            fields = line.split(';')
            userid = fields[0].strip('"')
            location = fields[1].strip('"')
            if len(fields) > 3:
                age = fields[2].strip().strip('"')
            else:
                age = 'NULL'
            if age != 'NULL':
                value = location + '  (age: ' + age + ')'
            else:
                value = location
            self.userid2name[userid] = value
            self.username2id[location] = userid
        f.close()
        print(i)


    def pearson(self, rating1, rating2):
        sum_xy = 0
        sum_x = 0
        sum_y = 0
        sum_x2 = 0
        sum_y2 = 0
        n = 0
        for key in rating1:
            if key in rating2:
                n += 1
                x = rating1[key]
                y = rating2[key]
                sum_xy += x * y
                sum_x += x
                sum_y += y
                sum_x2 += pow(x, 2)
                sum_y2 += pow(y, 2)
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        # now compute denominator
        denominator = (sqrt(sum_x2 - pow(sum_x, 2) / n)
                       * sqrt(sum_y2 - pow(sum_y, 2) / n))
        if denominator == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return (sum_xy - (sum_x * sum_y) / n) / denominator


    def computeNearestNeighbor(self, username):
        """creates a sorted list of users based on their distance to
        username"""
        distances = []
        for instance in self.data:
            if instance != username:
                distance = self.fn(self.data[username],
                                   self.data[instance])
                distances.append((instance, distance))
        # sort based on distance -- closest first
        distances.sort(key=lambda artistTuple: artistTuple[1],
                       reverse=True)
        return distances

    def recommend(self, user):
       """Give list of recommendations"""
       recommendations = {}
       # first get list of users  ordered by nearness
       nearest = self.computeNearestNeighbor(user)
       #
       # now get the ratings for the user
       #
       userRatings = self.data[user]
       #
       # determine the total distance
       totalDistance = 0.0
       for i in range(self.k):
          totalDistance += nearest[i][1]
       # now iterate through the k nearest neighbors
       # accumulating their ratings
       for i in range(self.k):
          # compute slice of pie 
          weight = nearest[i][1] / totalDistance
          # get the name of the person
          name = nearest[i][0]
          # get the ratings for this person
          neighborRatings = self.data[name]
          # get the name of the person
          # now find bands neighbor rated that user didn't
          for artist in neighborRatings:
             if not artist in userRatings:
                if artist not in recommendations:
                   recommendations[artist] = (neighborRatings[artist]
                                              * weight)
                else:
                   recommendations[artist] = (recommendations[artist]
                                              + neighborRatings[artist]
                                              * weight)
       # now make list from dictionary
       recommendations = list(recommendations.items())
       recommendations = [(self.convertProductID2name(k), v)
                          for (k, v) in recommendations]
       # finally sort and return
       recommendations.sort(key=lambda artistTuple: artistTuple[1],
                            reverse = True)
       # Return the first n items
       return recommendations[:self.n]

r = recommender(users)
# The author implementation
r.loadBookDB('/Users/danialt/Downloads/BX-Dump/')

# The alternative loading
ratings = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Book-Ratings.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
books = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Books.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")
users = pd.read_csv('/Users/danialt/BX-CSV-Dump/BX-Users.csv', sep=";", quotechar="\"", escapechar="\\")



pivot_rating = ratings.pivot(index='User-ID', columns='ISBN', values='Book-Rating')
```

Comment: Why two downvotes but no constructive comments? Seems clear to me, +1

Comment: @DanAllan I was wondering the same.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with benchmark such as this. Pandas might be using lazy loading, i.e. it may return but not actually have read the data yet. In which case the measured wall time would be worthless. Try performing some simple operation on all the data to ensure it has really been read.

As for correlation: your input matrix may be sparse, but the correlation matrix will likely be not that sparse; as there usually is some minimal correlation between anything.

Note that the correlation matrix will be square, i.e. if you have `100k` users, the user-user correlation matrix will be `100k x 100k` (you can save half of that memory due to symmetry, but doesn't help that much).

If you want to speed up computations, consider whether you need all the data, need it at full precision, and whether you can exploit data layout in memory to speed up computations.
For example covariance (as used in correlation) *can* be sped up easily by exploiting sparsity, and working on non-zero values in columns only instead of working in rows.

However, to become *really* fast, you will have to **abandon thinking in matrixes**. Instead, consider hashing and index structures that **avoid comparing everything with everything else** (which is naturally quadratic in cost). When thinking in matrixes, always think in *sparse* matrixes that don't really exist in your memory or on disk.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last paragraph? you meant hashing like this: http://www.google.com/trends/correlate/nnsearch.pdf? let's say I have a really this 300k users and 30k items. How should I proceed?

Comment: I did not read that article. I was referring to hashing as in "sketching and hashing" and "locality sensitive hashing".